# How can I filter quests for the actual region or at least for my level?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have a lot of quests on my 'to do' list. Many of them points far away from my actual position.

How can I filter quests for my actual position or region?

There are also many quests on a much higher level (in red), impossible to solve actually.
How can I hide such quests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a filter option for either distance or level.  Your best option is to start picking the lowest-level quests and work your way along them.  It's not the most desirable, but since there is no filter option for quests right now, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Assuming you're not against Quick Travel, as well, there's no real disadvantage to going to far-away quests.

Comment: even if you're againts it, the world is vibrant and beautiful enough to enjoy traveling :)

Comment: Could you please explain how my answer was wrong?  I admit that I didn't know that quests were sorted by proximity, but instead of correcting me nicely, you simply down vote an answer that is correct: there is no filter option.  Please explain.

Comment: Essentially, there are people who, despite all the evidence to the contrary, believe quests are automatically sorted by proximity. Laboring under this mistaken belief, they down vote you because they think you're wrong. It makes sense in context

Comment: @Dallium I don't know what other people see, hear, read, or experience but at least in 1.31 I noticed my quest generally are organized by region with the region I'm in at the top. For instance if I'm in Skelliege then those quests will be filtered above the Velen/Novigrad quests and vis-versa when I'm in Velen/Novigrad. The 'multiple location' quests generally stay at the top. I can't say if this logic was used to down vote this answer. I've given it an up-vote.

Answer (score -4):

Quests are automatically sorted from the closest to the furthest.

Comment: Are you really sure?

Comment: I noticed that myself then I did a quick google search and I found this: https://m.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/37zkgu/did_anyone_else_realize_that_quests_in_our/ note that some people think this is not the case but it's possible it has been patched in at some point.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I checked it multiple times after I read this and my quests were never sorted by distance. E.g. a quest that was 20 feet away from me was down on the list and one 2000 feet away was at the top. I'm playing on PS4 with patch 1.04.

Comment: No they aren't.